# Why the Matplotlib Pyplot cannot show the chart while Seaborn can?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, data-analysis

Here is the code and the execution result.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(19, 5, figsize=(20,80))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
for i in range(len(column_with_null)):
    
    row_loc = i // 5
    col_loc = i % 5
    
    axs[row_loc, col_loc].boxplot(x=data[column_with_null[i]])
    axs[row_loc, col_loc].set_title(column_with_null[i])

plt.show()
```

[image: Execution result of Matplotlib implementation]

It is quite weird that the axes and axis are normally shown but no charts(I mean the boxes themselves).

The thing is, **when I implement the same function with Seaborn, it works**.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(19, 5, figsize=(20,80))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
for i in range(len(column_with_null)):
    
    row_loc = i // 5
    col_loc = i % 5
    
    sns.boxplot(data=data[column_with_null[i]], ax=axs[row_loc, col_loc])
    axs[row_loc, col_loc].set_title(column_with_null[i])

plt.show()
```

[image: Execution result of Seaborn implementation]

There is no problem with my data, and I have added `%matplotlib inline`. I tried the code in Pycharm and ends up with the same result.

Does anyone who encountered similar problem before?

Environment:
conda 23.7.4
python 3.9.18
matplotlib 3.8.0
matplotlib-base 3.8.0
matplotlib-inline 0.1.6

Comment: Please share code as text, not images.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that seaborn skips the NaN entries. And matplotlib sees some of the data is NaN and decides no reliable boxplot can be drawn. Both points of view have their merit. You can explicitly filter out the NaNs.

Comment: There are two reasons to make a minimum, complete example that includes some pared-down or dummied data. One is that we can't explain the effect of something on your data without the data. The even better reason is that, while making minimal data, you are very likely to find the answer yourself.